# Aws beanstalk, mod_wsgi, python, process and threads

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I had a look at aws beanstalk app for Python and learned it uses Apache and mod_wsgi with a default setting of 1 process and 15 threads.

1) Does it mean that if a user upload a long file on the system, it will keep 1 thread busy, and context switch rapidly between the other threads so 1 user uploading a file will not block the entire app ?

2) If I have 2 cpus, should I increase the number of process = number of cpus ?

3) What's your personal experience with this aws beanstalk setup, do you feel your site is fast and responsive ? How much traffic does it handle on which type of aws BS EC2 ? I have no clue what such a mod_wsgi aws setup can deliver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A file upload is generally going to be I/O bound. The upload shouldn't cause any undue affects on the operation of the server and should not trigger any thread switching or Python global interpreter lock problems. What you need to worry about is how many long running uploads you might have running at the same time as the number of threads is limited by the configuration.

Overall, it is impossible for anyone to give you advice because how you set up the process/threads mix depends on your very specific application and only you know what the requirements are for your application. If you don't know yet, then you are worrying too early about how you may need to set it up. So write your application, run it, add monitoring so you know what it is doing and then you will have a better idea of how you might need to tune the server.

For some background on the various issues, go watch:

- [Using benchmarks to understand how WSGI servers work.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SGleKfigMsk)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As the author of mod wsgi, how many process you think I should run on a single cpu core aws EC2 ? Should I always restrict the number of processes so they are equal to the number of core ? Is there ANY advantage to have processes > cpu cores ?

Comment: As I said, one needs to know about the requirements your application has. So how many requests per second will you get. How long requests run for. Are they I/O bound of doing CPU intensive tasks. How much memory you have available. How much memory your application uses. There are two many variables that go into trying to work it out and one can't just guess.

Comment: I understand your point. Let's forget this specific case for a moment... as a general rule, is it true that there should never be more than 1 process (not talking about threads) per Cpu core, as 2 process can't benefit from any concurrency on a same core ?

Comment: No, the suggestion that you should only ever have at most one process per core is wrong. Similarly, the suggestion by many (coming from gunicorn), that a good general rule is that you have twice the number of processes as cores is wrong as well. It really depends on whether your application is I/O bound vs CPU bound, or to what degree. That video I pointed out in the question tries to explain some of these issues.